# Define pattern route for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I am using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) and express to make a web chat application. I have a question about routing.

My route is:

```
app.get("/", function( req, res ) {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/index.html" );
});
```

And as far as I know it means all clients should go to http://www.example.com/index.html page to access the chat. ( maybe, not sure )

**Is it possible to have a pattern URL like this:**

```
app.get("/*", function( req, res ) {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/*" );
});
```

so that any user can access to chat on any URL
**In short:** Something like facebook chat. which is accessible in all pages.

thanks in advance

Comment: For your example: `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`. But, I think you've misunderstood how Facebook's chat works. You need to look into client-side communication like [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) and [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets). And, those can be used from any page you choose to implement them for.

Comment: For using WebSockets, etc. with Node.js, you might try [socket.io](http://socket.io/). [Example](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/0.9.15/examples/chat).

Comment: I am using socket.io, but just I have problem in routing it. my chat application is almost complete. but it is only accessible in /index.html. because of my route.

Comment: That's because you don't route it. Socket.IO creates additional background/asynchronous connections to the server that it manages independently from any Express routes (through `socket.on()` and `socket.emit()`). Each "*page*" that intends to use Socket.IO will need to include `socket.io.js` and call `io.connect()`.

Comment: So I want to have access to localhost:4000/john or localhost:4000/jack! how can I do that? it outputs Error GET /john or /jack. I am really mixed up!!

Comment: You're asking 2 different questions without I think fully realizing it -- 1) "*How to create a wildcard route?*" 2) "*How to establish real-time communication in every page?*" The answer below will help with the 1st. But, it won't directly establish the 2nd. They will be separate parts of your overall application.

Comment: I want a wildcard route to establish a real-time communication in every page !!!! 2 questions in 1 now !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39004/discussion-between-ali-a-and-jonathan-lonowski)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a pattern URL like this:

Yeah, Express supports exactly the route you listed. The documentation refers to it as an "*unnamed wild-card*."

```
// GET /foo     -> (200) "foo"
// GET /baz/qux -> (200) "baz/qux"

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params[0]);
});
```

Though, for your example, Express/Connect includes a [`static()` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) for serving files by combining the URL path to a base directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

---

> Something like facebook chat. which is accessible in all pages.

This wouldn't necessarily have much of a relation to routing. Your application may need a route to gather a list of contacts or other persisted data, but the actual "*chat*" will be managed separately.

In general, it would depend on including common content in each page -- perhaps via a "*layout*" or "*inheritance*" if you're using views/templates -- to display the form for inputting message and an area to display chat history. Also, a fair amount of the "*work*" for the chat will have to be done client-side.

A quick example would be to serve the same file for multiple URLs:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

var chat = io
    .of('/chat') // namespace
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            chat.emit('message', data);
        });
    });

server.listen(3000);
```

And, in that file:

```
<div id="chat-log"></div>
<form id="chat-send">
    <input name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-send');
    var chatLog = document.getElementById('chat-log');

    var chatSocket = io.connect('/chat');

    chatSocket.on('message', function (data) {
        chatLog
            .appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.text));
    });

    chatForm.onsubmit = function () {
        chatSocket.emit('message', {
            text: chatForm.message.value
        });

        chatForm.message.value = '';
        chatForm.message.focus();
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Then, from any address (`GET /`, `GET /foo`, `GET /bar/baz/qux`), you can access chat.

Comment: very thanks for such a great reply. I already made a chat exactly like facebook in both client and server side. but my problem is about accessing it in all URLs. I am going to use PHP Laravel for this. which supports layouts and also all URLs first refer to index.php and then rendering. I wonder if I define a /index.php it will work in all my pages while I developed my website with laravel...!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to use a url param like this:

```
app.get("/:chatter",function(req,res){
    console.log("the chatter is",req.param('chatter'));
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/index.html" );
    ...
});
```